# Find me Mongo equivalent of a SQL which has distinct, group and order by

Tags: sql, mongodb

Please help me find the MongoDb equivalent for the SQL:

```
select val from tblName where colName1 = 7 
group by colName2 
order by colName3 desc, colName4 desc
```

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For everything except the grouping :

```
db.tblName.find({colName1:7},{val:1}).sort({colName3:-1, colName4:-1})
```

But for grouping, you are either looking at [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) or the new [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) (the Aggregation Framework isn't in a stable build yet, it is only in 2.1.0 and odd-numbered releases aren't production ready)

With the Aggregation Framework, based upon a quick scan of the documentation and no access to the latest Mongo (ie copy & pasting won't work - it's a basis on which to start):

```
db.tblName.aggregate(
    {$match : {colName1:7}}, //filter by colName1=7
    {$project: {val:1,colName2:1,colName3:1,colname4:1}}, //keep only the specified fields
    {$group: {colname2:1}}, //group by colName2 - this is the bit I'm least clear on
    {$sort: {colName3:-1; colname4:-1}}, //sort
    {$project: {val:1}} //keep only the val column
)
```

If anyone wants to improve on the syntax (ie someone with access to a Mongo with Aggregation) feel free :)

Comment: I need that along with grouping, anyways thanks for your effort.

Comment: I've added a basis for grouping using the Aggregation Framework